# swiper.js if is parameter and if not

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have js function in slider(swiper.js), that checks if this is the last slide and after adds some inline css to another div. But after I go back on the previous slide, this inline css stays on the div. I need to do like - if this is the last slide = do this css, if not = do nothing. How can I reach this? What I need to add? Thanks!

```
  galleryTop.on('reachEnd', function () {
    var nFilter = document.getElementById('left-side-meta');
    nFilter.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
  });
```

Comment: You can use the event `slideChange` and the `galleryTop.realIndex` property to set/unset the style?

Comment: I' dont know how it would be like.. Where does 'galleryTop.realIndex' goes? Thanks!

galleryTop.on('slideChange', function () {
    if (mySwiper.reachEnd) {
            //my css
        }
});

Comment: `galleryTop.realIndex` goes inside the callback function. `If realIndex === lastSlideIndex -> display: none, else, display: unset`

Comment: Jonathan, Can You answer topic with your version of js please? Thanks.

I tried this, do not work.

  galleryTop.on('reachEnd', function () {
      if (galleryTop.realIndex) {
          var nFilter = document.getElementById('jail-app-left-side-meta');
          nFilter.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
      }
      else {
        var nFilter2 = document.getElementById('jail-app-left-side-meta');
        nFilter2.setAttribute("style", "display: block");
      }
  });

Comment: No More need, worked answer of kgmt, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `slideChange` and `isEnd`

```
galleryTop.on('slideChange', function () {
    if (galleryTop.isEnd) {
        var nFilter = document.getElementById('left-side-meta');
        nFilter.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will have the same problem as the posted question as the inline css will remain there when navigating. You can add an `else` and remove the css if false.

Comment: Tried this from another topic, do not work for this case.. I read Swiper api there is no more function 'slideChangeEnd' as I can see. THANKS

Comment: Thank You so much! Works perfect, I forgot to change the ID of div, my fault.  Have a great day^